# Squid 2.7 : display custom error page on deny connect (503)

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, http-proxy

After some research, I finally managed to apply our company's blocked sites list to https/ssl websites using a "deny CONNECT" acl.

However, when a user tries to access a blocked website, he only sees the default 503 error page from his browser, instead of our standard access denied page.

Is there anyway to configure SQUID to display an error page instead of the browser's error page ?

Comment: I think it's the browser's choice. It's not up to Squid.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the question, you are having problems with HTTPS sites?

I am currently investigating how to make it happen as well.  Squid in the middle (breaking ssl) is an option, but one I don't want to take yet.

I split ours into two files and acl until this can get resolved.  I use this for https:

```
deny_info TCP_RESET acl
```

It will not tell them to try to change network proxy settings, just saying it network connection reset.

Comment: Yes, its with HTTPS websites. For the time being, I'm using always_direct until we get our hands on our new FW solution.